# Not able to connect to Teradata using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, sdk, teradata

I am trying to connect to Teradata using jdbc. My application is running in JDK 1.4.

The url i am using is "jdbc:teradata:///TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8";

I get "No suitable driver error" when i try to run using JDK 1.4. 
However, I am able to run my app using JDK 1.7 with the same url.

I have both terajdbc4.jar and tdgssconfig.jar in my Netbeans libraries.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a version that is compatible with Java 1.4? The name `terajdbc4.jar` suggests it is for Java 6 (JDBC 4).

Answer (score 0):

You probably use the wrong version of either Java, Teradata JDBC or Teradata Utilities (TTU).

Take a look here, what is compatible with what: [Compatibility](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/platformMatrix.html)

The matrix is part of this [reference](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html) which holds information how to use JDBC with different Application Server like JBoss, Tomcat, WebSphere, ColdFusion, WebLogic, SAP etc.